# Rows are coming undefined when calling function in postgreysql

Tags: c#

i wrote functon like when i am calling function 
select * from fngettalukbydistrict();
iam getting rows to field but it is defined undefined.

function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sde.fngettalukbydistrict(IN districtname text)
  RETURNS table(districtname text) AS
$BODY$
select distinct talukname from village where districtname=$1 order by talukname
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION sde.fngettalukbydistrict(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

public DataTable Getalltaluksbydistrict(String districtname)
        {
            return Helper.ExecuteSelectCommand("select * from fngettalukbydistrict('" + districtname + "');", CommandType.Text);           public DataTable Getalltaluksbydistrict(String districtname)
        {
            return AgricultureDetailsDAL.Getalltaluksbydistrict(districtname);
        }

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: i wrote function as above.and i am calling that function for dependent dropdown i am getting rows undefined

Comment: Yes, i am getting rows as undefined..i am able to bind rows but value is coming as 'undefined'

Comment: i no need to return anything..

Comment: Try to execute `select distinct talukname from village where districtname='pass_districtname_here' order by talukname` and let us knoew whether you get a row or not

Comment: Yes, I am getting corresponding taluknames when i execute by paiing parameter.when i call the function i am getting for dropdowns rows are like undefined

Comment: Try this http://hastebin.com/wagojatido.pas

Comment: What happened when you add the `RETURN QUERY` before your SQL query? Nothing?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: `RETURN QUERY` works when function uses `PLPGSQL` not `SQL`

Comment: @indu Does your function returns the correct rows that your expecting?, If yes the actual problem may be something else  as you said _when i call the function i am getting for dropdowns rows are like undefined_, here which programming language are you using to fill the `dropdowns` ??

Comment: @wingedpanther.. yes i am getting correct rows..i am using  c# to bind data.and ajax for dropdown.

Comment: @indu: I think you have some data binding issue in your C# code. check it again.

Comment: @indu So you should revamp this question with C# code and tag c#

Comment: @indu: Kindly share the C# code also.

Comment: public DataTable Getalltaluksbydistrict(String districtname)
        {
            return Helper.ExecuteSelectCommand("select * from fngettalukbydistrict('" + districtname + "');", CommandType.Text);           public DataTable Getalltaluksbydistrict(String districtname)
        {
            return AgricultureDetailsDAL.Getalltaluksbydistrict(districtname);
        }

Comment: @indu: Please add it to your question not in comment.

Comment: my web method  [WebMethod]
        public String Getalltaluksbydistrict(String districtname)
        {
            DataTable dt = AgricultureDetailsBAL.Getalltaluksbydistrict(districtname);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
        } my ajax call

Comment: Thanks for all ur reply..its working now.the problem is i need to return the field names....

Comment: corrected one CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sde.fngettalukbydistrict(IN districtname text)
      RETURNS table(talukname text) AS
    $BODY$
    select distinct talukname from village where districtname=$1 order by talukname
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
      COST 100
      ROWS 1000;
    ALTER FUNCTION sde.fngettalukbydistrict(text)
      OWNER TO postgres;